# Import on-premise RDBMS data into AWS Athena

Tags: python-3.x, database-migration, rdbms, amazon-athena

I am looking for ways to import RDBMS data into AWS Athena in a cost effective way using only Python as a tool. I am able to do the above using PySpark but now I only have to use Python.
Can someone suggest some tutorials for this?

Comment: what is the rdbms source?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [AWS Lake Formation](https://aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/), which is a service that they launched last year to help people get their data from on premises RDBMS to Athena/EMR/Redshift.

Comment: I need to use only Python in a Glue script.